# Goutte extract data from every node

Tags: php, goutte

hi i want to extract data from every node but i don't know how to do it and really appreciated if someone give me some guidance

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>item1</td>
        <td>item2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>item3</td>
        <td>item4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and here it is my php code:

```
$client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'https://www.socom');

    $crawler->filter('.tr')->each(function ($node) {
        print $node->filter('.td')->text()."\n";
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in the right way, just you're referring to your html tags which have the class `tr` and as I've seen in your html you have none, so, that's why you don't have "success".

Check this, you can access to every one of your `tr` elements and to get the text inside this way:

```
$crawler->filter('tr')->each(function($node) {
  print_r($node->text());
});
```

Notice the output is a `node` so you can't use `echo`, and there I'm using just `tr` to make a reference to the element.

And also you can do this, that's more seemed maybe to what you wanted to get:

```
$crawler->filter('tr')->each(function($node) {
  $node->filter('td')->each(function($nested_node) {
    echo $nested_node->text() . "\n";
  });
});
```

This is get all the `tr` over every `tr` get its `td` and then over those `td` elements get the text inside.

And that's it, this is the code.

```
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();

$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'your_url');

$crawler->filter('tr')->each(function($node) {
  print_r($node->text());
});

$crawler->filter('tr')->each(function($node) {
  $node->filter('td')->each(function($nested_node) {
    echo $nested_node->text() . "\n";
  });
});
```

Hope it helps.